# Is google.protobuf.Int32Value compatible with google.protobuf.Int64Value?

Tags: protocol-buffers

According to the [documentation](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/#updating), plain int32 and int64 are compatible. But what about google.protobuf.Int32Value and google.protobuf.Int64Value? How does one go about updating an Int32Value to Int64Value?

Answer (score 0):

The *name* of messages is not encoded into the payload in protobuf (apart from if you're using "any" and dealing with that type directly). If we look at [wrappers.proto](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/wrappers.proto), we can see that the *only* difference between `Int32Value` and `Int64Value` is the field type, being `int32` and `int64` respectively. Since (as you already discovered) these *are* reasonably interchangeable (if we ignore problems of a newer `int64` client sending data to an older `int32` server and getting overflows or misinterpreted data), yes: you *should* be safe to simply change the field type in your definition from `Int32Value` to `Int64Value`, and update any usage accordingly. As already hinted: you probably want to be careful about how you deploy this, so that nobody uses 64-bit values until everyone can handle them, but: an `int64` with a value in the 32-bit range should look identical on the wire to an `int32` with a value in the 32-bit range. In particular, you should still be able to read any persisted pre-existing data that used `Int32Value`, without problem.